# What is the largest score possible in Google Play Games Leaderboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

What is the biggest number I can save to Google Play Games Leaderboard as a score?
I am using Google Play Games API and its leaderboard feature. I am using BigInteger to keep track of players' score but Play Games API only accept long variable when saving the score. I want to know if I can save more than the biggest number of long variables can keep.
And what is the biggest number I can save on the leaderboard so if players score more than that number I can fix the score with that number and save it?

Comment: The documentation seems to suggest they are integers, which I would assume to be 32 bit? https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards Do you really need BigInteger in your case?

Comment: Use `ToString` and `Parse` on c# side?

Comment: @Bart You can save the score with long to the leaderboard, I tried it. I was using ulong before but I saw a couple of players reach the largest number of ulong. Then I decided to use BigInteger so they can increase their score. But unfortunately, I can't increase the number on the leaderboard. Maybe my score system should tend to increase slower.

Comment: @derHugo I didn't understand what you mean but I already converting string to big integer or big integer to string as I needed. I am saving the high score to the application's local registry as a string. No problem with that.

Comment: There is a basic issue you are overlooking. Why would you want to save scores in the thousands of trillions, with an accuracy of single digits? Thats like measuring your height in microns. Go old school and use smaller numbers with extra 000s displayed on the end 

Comment: @iCollect.itLtd Yes, it was something I could not foresee at the beginning that the numbers could be this large. But my game is a puzzle game and it's all about numbers and mathematical operations, so it's very important to me that the numbers are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value of a signed 64-bit long variable in Java is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. This is the largest number you can save using a long variable, and it is also the maximum value that can be saved on the Play Games leaderboard.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to be able to save bigger scores but anyway, there's nothing we can do.